# Is it possible to use an environment variable in a pkg-config.pc file?

Tags: gcc, ld, pkg-config

I'm trying to use a library `libfoo.so` that will be installed in `$(LIBDIR)/foo/` where `$(LIBDIR)` is an environment variable that can be different based on the build setup.

In order for other components to correctly link with this library, they need to have the correct LDFLAGS set, namely they need to have `-L$(LIBDIR)/foo -lfoo` set. In order to make this a bit more generic, I would like to add a libfoo.pc file to libfoo with these flags set. My file currently has the following contents:

```
Name: libfoo
Description: Example library
Version: 1.0.0
Libs: -L$(LIBDIR)/foo -lfoo
```

My other component which uses libfoo has the following simplified makefile:

```
all:
    $(CC) bar.c -o out $(shell pkg-config --libs libfoo)
```

The library is correctly found by pkg-config, but running `make` gives the following error:

```
$ make
cc bar.c -o out -L$(LIBDIR)/foo -lfoo
/bin/sh: LIBDIR: command not found
```

In other words, `$(LIBDIR)` is not expanded into the value that is set as an environment variable. Is it possible to use environment variables or makefile variables in .pc files?

Comment: Have you tried `$LIBDIR` without parenthesis?

Comment: Yes without parenthesis it results in `cc bar.c -o out -L$LIBDIR/foo -lfoo`, which no longer gives the "command not found" error, but it doesn't help with the linking either

Comment: What other error do you get then?

Comment: Then I get the following linker error:
`cc bar.c -o out -L$LIBDIR/foo -lfoo`
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
`make: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 1`
which is as expected, because the library cannot be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--define-variable`.

`Makefile`:

```
    $(CC) bar.c -o out $(shell pkg-config --define-variable=LIBDIR=$(LIBDIR) --libs libfoo)
```

`libfoo.pc`:

```
Libs: -L${LIBDIR}/foo -lfoo
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using environment variables inside `pkg-config.pc` files is not possible.

As a workaround I will instead add a prefix variable to the .pc file which is filled in or overwritten by a script before my `bar` component is compiled.